# How to send plain text from Javascript to NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, pug

I'm building an online compiler using ExpressJS,Pug and ACE for editor. My idea is to let users type their code in the editor, send the code back to the server and save it into a txt file then using ChildProcess to compile the code there and return the output back to users.
Here is the problem i'm facing:
I want a Run button that send a POST request to the server including the code typed by user, here is my implement so far

```
    script.
            console.log('client-side script running :D');
            const button = document.getElementById('runbutton');
            button.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
                const code = editor.getValue();
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("POST","/run",true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www- 
   form-urlencoded");
                xhttp.send(code);
                console.log(code);
            });
```

and btw i'm using AJAX to avoid refreshing the page. But the problem here is when server received the code, it usually end up with more or less character than the actual code due to the JSON format so I cannot save and compile the code correctly. How do I send the raw code in plain text format from the client side to the server ?

here the server side code im using

```
     app.post('/run',(req,res) => {
    console.log('Server route running');
    const code = req.body; // code => still an object not yet a string
    const codePath = path.join(__dirname,"public","CODE","code.txt"); //   PROJECT/public/CODE/code.txt is created
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(codePath); // create a write stream
    stream.write(JSON.stringify(code)); // save the stringify object
    stream.end();
    console.log(code);
    res.end();
});
```

[here is the different between the client code and server received code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kawqs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the content type of your request to use `Content-Type: text/plain` like this:

```
 xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/plain");
```

Comment: I did but then the server receive nothing, idk why

Comment: Could you post an example of the code that you are using on your server ?